# How to minimize a window using mouse in PCManFM?

Tags: mouse, window, minimize, pcmanfm

How can I minimize a window using mouse in PCManFM?

I'm using Elementary Desktop Environment in Ubuntu 12.04

**Update**

I tried to bring the minimize button back by opening `gconf-editor`

and change the value of `/apps/metacity/general/button_layout` from `close:maximize` to `close,minimize:maximize`.

Then I logged out and back in, but that change was simply ignored.

**Update Again**

Screenshot
[image]

And the System settings

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found some thing [here](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/04/elementary-gtk-theme-30-released.html)

As of Elementary GTK theme 3.0,

- The default placement is now close:maximize
- The maximize button has been changed from the "+" (typically used to mean new) to two opposing arrows

The reason for not having minimize button is stated [here](http://elementaryos.org/journal/whats-window-controls)

Comment: Finally got it, Use middle/scroll mouse button to minimize the window

Answer (score 2):

First check if you can see the following button on your windows:

[image]

If so, just click it, because this is the minimize button.

If you could not see this button, you will have to enable this button, so follow this tutorial:

Open the menu (if you are using PCManFM you're probably using Lubuntu):

[image]

Go to "Preferences" > "Customize Look and Feel"

On Customize Look and Feel copy the following configuration:

[image]

Then click "Apply" and close it, so check the changes opening the File Manager (PCManFM in this case).

I hope I helped you.

Comment: Please see the System settings screenshot, it does not include  "Customize Look and Feel" :-(